# Make text appear one character at a time in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I'm making a little Terminal thingie and I want to add the ability for text to be "typed in" one character at a time. Right now what I am doing is looping over the string, inserting a character, and then calling `Thread.sleep`(forTimeInterval:). However, as you can see in the `gif` below, it doesn't print out the characters one at a time, it just waits until the whole for loop has finished and then displays the text. What do I need to do to make it update the display once each loop? (I tried `setNeedsDisplay:`, but I don't think that did anything.)
EDIT: here's the code (where console is a `UITextView`):

```
func appToConsole(input:ProgramResponse) {
    for line in input {
        var textProgress = self.token
        var oldText = console.text ?? ""
        for char in line.text.characters {
            textProgress.append(char)
            console.text = textProgress + oldText
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval(line.textSpeed))
        }
        textProgress += "\n"
        console.text = textProgress + oldText
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Update your question with relevant code as text (not as an image).

Comment: NEVER sleep on the main thread. Period.